How can i login into my bitcoin account if i forget password and two account
I accidentally crate two bitcoin account, and at the same time I forgot the old account password, so how can I login into  my old account

This question is similar to: I have lost my wallet, what can I do?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
